# export * vs named export making difference with module augmentation

Tags: typescript

Say I have two directories `a` and `b` with `class A` in directory `a` and `class B` in `b`. When I have module augmentation for `class A` in directory `b` whether I export `A` from directory `a` as `export *` or `export { A }` seems to make difference. The former imports `A` only as a type (interface) and not value (class). But the later imports it as a value as well. Why should the way it is exported matter?

Below is bare minimum code to reproduce this with Typescript 4.2.3.

Directory a:

a.ts

```
class A {
  _b: any;
}
export { A };
```

index.ts

```
export * from './a'; // <- this results in importing only type

// export { A } from './a'; <- this will import value as well
```

Directory B:

b.ts

```
import { A } from '../a'; // <- error here that A is being used as a type with importsNotUsedAsValues set to error

class B {
   v: number = 42;
}

declare module '../a' {
    interface A {
       readonly b: B;
    }
}

/* Object.defineProperty(A.prototype,'b', {
   get(this: A) {
     if(!this._b) this._b = new B();
     return this._b;
   }
}); */ // <- commented as the module augmentation implementation seems irrelevant.

console.debug(A); // <- Error that A here can't be used as a value

export { B };
```

Comment: `"importsNotUsedAsValues": false`

Comment: This will stop showing error on the import line but the error where the value is being used (the console.debug statement above) still errors that it is not a value.